# Watin don't update button after select option in list

Tags: c#, watin

I try to select one option in the following html :

```
<select class="gwt-ListBox" style="" gwtdebugid="signup-flow-choose-timezones">
   <option value="">Ahora seleccione una zona horaria:</option>
   <option value="">------</option>
   <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">(GMT-10:00) Hora de Hawai</option>
   <option value="America/Anchorage">(GMT-09:00) Hora de Alaska</option>
   <option value="America/Los_Angeles">(GMT-08:00) Hora del Pacífico</option>
   <option value="America/Denver">(GMT-07:00) Hora de las Montañas Rocosas</option>
   <option value="America/Phoenix">(GMT-07:00) Hora de las Montañas Rocosas - Arizona</option>
   <option value="America/Chicago">(GMT-06:00) Hora central</option>
   <option value="America/New_York">(GMT-05:00) Hora del Este</option>
</select>
```

When this option is selected good via click for example in the web page one button is enabled.
I try to select with the following code :

```
var option = ie.SelectList(Find.By("gwtdebugid", s => s.Equals("signup-flow-choose-timezones"))).Options[3];
option.Select();
option.Change();
```

But with this code the button remains disabled, nothing happens.

I try to run too JQuery code with the `Eval()` function in Watin in the following way :

```
ie.DomContainer.Eval("$('select.gwt-ListBox').change();");
```

But I get the following exception :

```
ReferenceError: '$' is not defined.
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here how i do this

```
//My drop down list
SelectList ddlAccounts = ie.SelectList(Find.ById("ddlClientNumbers_m_ddl"));    
//here i select option that i need
ddlAccounts.Options[i].Select();
//Or select by value your case
ddlAccounts.SelectByValue("Pacific/Honolulu");
```

you can add to be sure that browser is finished to load

```
 ie.WaitForComplete();
```

Buy i think you problem in another place if you button in Frame and not in ie,,sow that mean you need to load your frame each time after  `ddlAccounts.Options[i].Select();`

```
Frame yourFrame = ie.Frame(Find.ById("id"));
SelectList ddlAccounts = ie.SelectList(Find.ById("ddlClientNumbers_m_ddl"));    
ddlAccounts.SelectByValue("Pacific/Honolulu"); 
//and load frame again
yourFrame = ie.Frame(Find.ById("id"));
```

and the you can look for you updated button